# $F/K$ algebraic and every nonconstant polynomial in $K[X]$ has a root in $F$ implies $F$ is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F/K$ be an algebraic extension of fields in characteristic zero.  If $F/K$ is normal, and every nonconstant polynomial $f \in K[X]$ has a root in $F$, then $F$ is algebraically closed.  This is obvious, because if $u$ is algebraic over $F$ (let us agree to fix some algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$ containing $F$ with $u \in \overline{K}$), then it is algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial $f \in K[X]$, which by hypothesis must have one and therefore all of its roots in $F$.  In particular $u \in F$.

I have heard that the above assertion remains true if we drop the assumption that $F/K$ is normal.  But it seems to be a nontrivial result.  Can anyone get me started on how to prove this?

Thoughts so far: It's enough to show that every algebraic extension of $K$ is $K$-isomorphic to a subfield of $F$.  Certainly this is true for every finite extension $E$ of $K$; we're in characteristic zero, so $E = K(v)$ for some $v \in E$.  If $f \in K[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $v$ over $K$, then $f$ has some root $u \in F$, whence $E$ is $K$-isomorphic to the subfield $K(u)$ of $F$.

So, I'm thinking next use some kind of Zorn's Lemma argument?

Comment: Isn't it simpler, and perhaps more constructive to show that every polynomial in $F$ is obtained by composition of polynomials in $K$?

Comment: @Asaf Say $F=\mathbb C$ and $K=\mathbb R$, and $p(x)=x-i$. What do you mean by "composition" here?

Comment: @Andres: I mean that in the sense that we can write $x^2+1$ instead of $i$. I am being a bit inaccurate here, mainly as a consequence of writing from a cellphone, but I hope my meaning is clear. In model theoretic terms, all the objects which can be described with formulas with parameters from $F$ can be described with parameters from $K$.

Comment: @Asaf Now you have to argue that just because $p\in K[x]$ has a root in $F$ then actually $p$ splits in $F$.

Comment: (@Asaf And yes, I agree that all of this is true, and simpler than the approach suggested in the original post.)

Comment: (@Asaf By the way, I've always liked this fact. A memory from my undergraduate days: Just from the logical complexity of the field axioms, we know that the union of an increasing chain of fields is a field. So, if for every $i\in\mathbb N$, we have that $F_{i+1}$ is an algebraic extension of $F_i$ and every polynomial in $F_i[x]$ has a root in $F_{i+1}$, then $\bigcup_i F_i$ is the algebraic closure of $F_0$. But in fact $\bigcup_i F_i=F_1$. This showed me very early that model theory and algebra should really be considered a unit.)

Comment: (@Andres: François Dorais commented with a lovely forcing based construction of an algebraic closure somewhere on my blog recently.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E/F$ be a finite extension (which is separable as the characteristic is zero), we will prove that $E=F$, hence $F$  is algebraically closed:
Let $a$ be a primitive element of $E/F$. Then $a$ is algebraic over $K$, so there exists a finite Galois extension $N/K$  containing $a$, in particular 
$$
E\subseteq NF.
$$
(One can take $N$ to be the Galois closure of $K(a)$, for example.)
Let $f\in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of a primitive element of $N$ over $K$. Since $N/K$ is Galois, any of the roots of $f$ generates $N$ over $K$.

Now, by assumption $f$ has a root in $F$, so $N\subseteq F$, hence $E\subseteq NF=F$. This proves that $F$ has no non-trivial extensions, hence $F$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1):

The question asked is more specific than the title: in the question you say $K$ has characteristic $0$, but the title is a broader question. The answer to the broader question is also "yes". That is, even when $K$ has characteristic $p$ the field $F$ is algebraically closed. This is a theorem of Robert Gilmer. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315743?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) or Theorem 2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/algclosure.pdf).

Comment: I don't have access to the jstor article (by Robert Gilmer) you refer, but your presentation as theorem 2 is really nice and elementary. Thanks (+1) for the same.