# Prove verification that F is algebraic closure of K

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This question was asked in my Field Theory Quiz and I Think I need help to prove it.

> Let F be an algebraic extension of K such that every polynomial in K[x] has a root in F. Then show that F is an algebraic closure of K.

Attempt: F will be called Algebraically closed field if every polynomial $ f\in F[x]$    has a root in F.  Let f be given polynomial with coefficients in F. Then I need too prove  that f has at least 1 root in F using only that any polynomial in K[x] has a roots in F. I am at loss of ideas and unable to move foreward.

I removed proof verification tag as it was a terrible proof.

Comment: The proof isn’t correct, you need to show that every polynomial in $F$ has a root in $F$, which is stronger than every polynomial in $K$ having a root in $F$.

Comment: @Slade I am working on it again now as it was posted 8 months ago. I will add a new attempt

Comment: @Slade I think proof of user : cos_dm_math21 is great.

Comment: You question has inconsistencies. At one place (the quotation) you state that every polynomial in $K[x] $ has a root in $F$ and in your attempt you assume that every polynomial in $K[x] $ has all roots in $F$. The accepted answer also uses the same assumption.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing out. I am editing and I am looking for solution with has any polynomial in K[x] has a root in F. Can you please guide?

Comment: There is a standard theorem by name of Gilmer which says that if every polynomial in $K[x] $ has a root in $F$ then every polynomial in $K[x] $ has all roots in $F$. Is it provided in your textbook? The proof is a bit complicated.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No unfortunately it's not. I followed Algebra by Thomas Hungerford and it was not part of text there.

Comment: I will check if this is available on mathse

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much!

Comment: See the references in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3507595/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I am a bit busy. Will check after some time. Thanks a lot for your guidence!